# Firebase account creation trying to set additional info using variables and then getting that information

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, account, creation

So, on one document (register.html), I have this code:

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).catch(function(error) {
                    // Handle Errors here.
                    var errorCode = error.code;
                    var errorMessage = error.message;
                    // [START_EXCLUDE]
                    if (errorCode == 'auth/weak-password') {
                      weakPass.style="color:red;";
                    }

                            else {
                        unexpected.innerHTML=errorMessage;
                    }
                    console.log(error);

//Handle Account Status
    firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {

    if(user) {
            var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
            var firstname = txtFirst.value;
            var lastname = txtLast.value;
            var School = dropdown.value;

            user.updateProfile({
                firstName: firstname,
                lastName: lastname,
                school: School
            }).then(function() {
                alert("User: " + user + " Firstname: " + user.firstName + " Lastname: " + user.lastName + " School: " + user.school);
                redirect("home.html");
            });


            //After successful login, user will be redirected to home.html
    }

    });
```

While the user does, in fact, register with an email and a password that is hooked up to the firebase website, and successfully redirects the website to home.html, I don't think it actually adds the data to the users "profile".

I have this code on home.html in attempt to pull the data:

```
//Handle Account Status
  firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
    if (user) {
      // User is signed in.
      var firstname = user.firstName;
      var lastname = user.lastName;
      var school = user.school;

      alert("User: " + user + " Firstname: " + firstname + " Lastname: " + lastname + " School: " + school);
    } else {
      // User is signed out.
    }

  });
```

However, this doesn't work. The value of **user** is true, but the alert returns **undefined** when the **alert** is called. The alert shows this exactly:
"User: [object Object] Firstname: undefined Lastname: undefined School undefined"

What am I doing wrong? Is there a different/better way to store user data using firebase?
The only data I storing for users is their first name, last name, and school, as well as the obvious like email and password because that DOES work.

To be honest, I don't know if there's just something wrong with the way I'm setting the data, or pulling the data, or how to test either.

Comment: Hey, and welcome to SO :) I can see that you have put some effort into making your question easy to read. However, you might want to narrow down your exact problem a little bit more in order to better stick to this website [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). In particular, I'm sure that you can boil you code down to a smaller [minimal example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that'll make it easier for people to spot the problem in there :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [guides](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users#update_a_users_profile),

> You can update a user's basic profile information—the user's display
>   name and profile photo URL—with the updateProfile method.

So the only values you can change using `updateProfile()` are `displayName` and `photoUrl`. It is not possible to add arbitrary profile fields to a user. Instead, you'll want to store extra information about a user in a database, such as [Cloud Firestore](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/). If you'd like more info on [Cloud Firestore](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/firestore-web/index.html?index=..%2F..%2Findex#0), this codelab is a great place to start.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for the link too!